# Adding XML decleration to soap message

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, soap, soap-client

I am trying to add a XML Declaration for ex: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` to the top of this soap message. Can anyone assist me on how this can be done?

```
 try {
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            String url = "http://ws.cdyne.com/emailverify/Emailvernotestemail.asmx";
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

            // Process the SOAP Response
            printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

            soapConnection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
        MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
        SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
        SOAPHeader header = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader();
```

Comment: soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION ,Boolean.TRUE) should enable you to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set a property to the SOAP message.

```
soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true")
```

The above code should do that.

Here is the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/soap/SOAPMessage.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to `setProperty(String property, Object value)` documentation.

Comment: How can I make a print statment which will include all code? Headers etc? I can submit my whole code if needed, I can print the soap structure, but not my headers.addHeader( , ) content.

Comment: you can do something like: ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   soapMessage.writeTo(baos);
   System.out.println( baos.toString());

Comment: Can you give me further help through email? I have one more further question regarding my code.

Comment: sure :), post it here , if you'd like to

Comment: Have you ever dealt with parsing before? EX: parsing xml file to variables? I'm used to the old fashion way, but am looking for something a bit easier if the xml code changes. I can supply code. Please reply on here if your capable of it. Otherwise, my email is 'ixc21@live.com'

Comment: Thanks. Note that the value parameter will be expecting true or false in String so sending `Boolean,TRUE` will produce an error.

Answer (score 1):

```
soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING, "UTF-8");
soapMessage.setProperty(SOAPMessage.WRITE_XML_DECLARATION, "true");
```